# ReplaceAll - Position of list arguments not displayed properly

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, symbolic, rule

This code

```
A[1, 2, 4, 5] /. A[a___] -> Position[{a}, 4]
```

return `{}`

Why this code not return 3 (a position of number 4) ?

I noticed that {a} is not evaluate to {1,2,3,4}. When we write this code as

```
A[1, 2, 4, 5] /. A[a___] -> Position[{a}, a]
```

return `{1}`  (position of not evaluated letter a)

**Is there a simple cure to this not evaluation problem.**

Comment: Try using `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) when matching patterns.

Comment: Also, not sure if that's a toy example or not, but `Position[A[1, 2, 4, 5], 4]` works because `Position` can operate on `Heads` other than `List`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "official-ize" my comments above, use `RuleDelayed`:

```
A[1, 2, 4, 5] /. A[a__] :> Position[{a}, 4]
```

> `{{3}}`

The reason to use `RuleDelayed` here is the same as `SetDelayed`. They both keep the *rhs* unevaluated until the rule is used, meaning that once the pattern matches on the *lhs*, `a__` is substituted in for `a` on the *rhs*. Otherwise with normal `Rule`, *rhs* is evaluated before `a__` has the chance to be pattern matched.

And the example used by the OP maybe a toy example, but it is worth noting that `Position` works on heads other than `List` so

```
Position[A[1, 2, 4, 5], 4]
```

gives the same result.

Comment: Thank You :). RuleDelayed ...this is exactly what i need.